# Send Large File with Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress and I created a form with the Contact Form 7 plugin where the users can send videos to my email. I set a limit of 2GB (I set in bytes) but users cannot send anything. The page load for a long time and then it lose the conection.

Please, help. I need my users send videos to my email up to 2GB.

Comment: Don't most emails have a limit on an attachment size?

Comment: Contact form 7 is good for word press but not stable. Depends on the response in your server chances are there to miss your massage that sent form the client.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Maybe it can be a limit of the email server.